# An error while trying to build bundle with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I`ve just started to learn nodejs and react and I am trying to build bundle using webpack and I receive next error. How can I make it work?

```
C:\Users\Admin\WebstormProjects\reactandwebpacktests>webpack
C:\Users\Admin\WebstormProjects\reactandwebpacktests\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161
        return mod.npm require(id);
                       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
?[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)?[39m
```